# AdMob Banner in ShareSheet

Tags: ios, admob, ios-sharesheet

Is there any restriction that it is not possible to display a bannerview from Google Admob in a sharesheet? I have an app which provides additional data in the sharesheet, and I also want to display ads there. In my main app, the ads work fine - but in the sharesheet, I don't get any error message or anything when initialising the ads.

Greetings,
Jack

**Update**: I am using the cocoapod Firebase/Admob. This one is assigned to the main app and the sharesheet. As I have the ads on several view controlers, I created a function, which is connected via an app group to both parts. In ViewDidLoad, I initialice google admob

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "filledwiththecorrectcode")
```

Then I run this function providing the view and the constrains:

```
func loadAdd(ViewController: GADBannerView, HightConstrain: NSLayoutConstraint, MainApp: Bool){
        ViewController.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait

        // TEST CODE
        ViewController.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

        ViewController.rootViewController = self
        HightConstrain.constant = 50

        let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        ViewController.load(request)
    }
}
```

This works fine in the main app. In the sharesheet, I run the same function - it also walks through in the debugger, but nothing happens. Ah, the

Comment: I don't know if you can add AdMob view to share sheet. To be honest, I never tried to add a custom view to sharesheet. But at least you can check your GADAdSize constant. If you use "smart" ones, their size is calculated on the go. They may not be appear in the sharesheet.

Comment: Thank you for this tipp. I tried it with normal banner size and smart one - same results. It seems that they were not even initialised - I can not see anything in the logging.

Comment: Then these were the only things I can say for now. I have to try what you try to do, but I’m not at my computer. Wish could do more. I may give it a try in 2 days. Btw, share some codes to get a better help. Good luck.

Comment: Can you share some codes and a screenshot of your problem? I will give it a try.

Comment: I added my code and some more details.

Comment: The code you shared still not giving enough details to understand the problem. You are not giving any information about where do you add banner to the controller as a subview, how do you outlet hight constraint, where do you set banner's width etc.

Comment: I add the view in the storyboard. There I also add the constrains to the top and to and to the sides. The hight is also a constrain, which is connected to the view, and then is set in the above posted function. I have it in three views - two of th main app, one in the shared view - and only the shared view doesn't work. I now tried to set up the shared view in Google Admob as an own app - same result, no logging - in the main App, I can see "<Google> Advertising tracking may be disabled. To get test ads on this device, enable advertising tracking." - not in the sharesheet.